# OnClick Event for Anchor Tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Is there an `onClick` event for anchor tags? I have the following line of code:

```
<li><a href="#" runat="server">Logout</a></li>
```

When the user clicks the logout text I want it to fire some code that would be in a method like this:

```
protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.RemoveAll();
    Session.Abandon();
}
```

What is the best practice at doing this in an anchor tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of standard html anchor tag, use the [`LinkButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this. It provides the functionality you're looking for.

Here you have a sample

```
<asp:LinkButton id="btnLogout" Text="Logout" OnClick="btnLogout_Click" runat="server"/>
```

It renders to an HTML anchor so visually it's the same as your code.

Answer (score 5):

yes, you can, but you need to add onserverclick attribute
  or use  asp Hyperlink control

```
  <a id="AnchorButton"
     onserverclick="AnchorButton_Click"
     runat="server">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do one thing, 
provide ID to the link button:

```
 <a runat="server" id="anchorTagButton">Click Me!!</a>
```

In the asp.net page load

```
anchorTagButton.ServerClick += new EventHandler(anchorTag_Click);
```

and finally

```
protected void anchorTag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        /*do stuff here*/
    }
```

Comment: Simple and neat! Thank you